# Is this running slow because it's in LINQ, or because i'm doing it in a poor way?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a data table with the following structure:

```
Foo1    Foo2    Value
A       2       5
B       4       20
C       6       30
B       6       4
```

I also have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
Foobar
    Foo1
        A
        B
        Other
    Foo2
        4
        6
        Other
```

(Note. There will be an unknown amount of columns / entries in foobar)

I need to iterate through my list, and for each element find the average Value in the data table that matches the sub elements value. For example, in Foo1 the average value for A in the data table is 5, B - 17.5, Other - 30.

```
Foobar
    Foo1
        A (average is 5)
        B (average is 17.5)
        Other (average is 30)
    Foo2
        4 (average is 20)
        6 (average is 17)
        Other (average is 5)
```

In actuality, the data table has ~50 columns and some large amount of rows. I'm fairly inexperienced with SQL/LINQ, so i'm not sure how to solve this problem in a way that isn't horribly slow. Especially for the "Other" bucket. My current strategy has been to just do a nested foreach, and then a LINQ query to select the Values that match the current sub element, and do the average. Something like this:

```
foreach (var foo in foobar)
{
    foreach (var bucket in foo.buckets) 
    {
        var hits = myDataTable.Where(n => n[foo.name].ToString() == bucket.name);
            if (hits.Any())
            {
                bucket.average = hits.Select(x => x["Value"]).Average();
            }
    }
}
```

It's very slow though. Is that because this is in LINQ, or because i'm doing this in a poor way?

**edit**

I've made some changes which have improved the speed, but it's still quite slow.

```
foreach (var foo in foobar)
{
    var pairs = myDataTable.Select(
        n => new {Name = n[foo.name], Value = n["Value"]});

    foreach (var bucket in foo)
    {
        var temp = pairs.Where(n => bucket.name == n.Name);
        bucket.average = temp.Any() ? temp.Select(x => x.Value).Average() : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your DataTable has a large number of rows it would make sense to do a foreach(DataRow dr in myDataTable.rows) on the outside instead of Linq on the inside.

Comment: You could use a LINQ group by on your rows, and in that way create sublists per Foo1. Then on the sublists do the average. Better let LINQ do most of the work or none of it. You lose your performance because of all the nesting.

Answer (score 5):

It's very slow because you're making a query every time you get to the innermost line, so instead of getting everything you want in 1 query you're getting N queries back & forth to the database (N being foobar.Count * foo.buckets.Count)

This can't be your whole code (storing something into a local variable and doing nothing with it) please post your whole method and i'll be happy to provide you with a much faster alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get all the results you want in Linq.

```
var res1 = from f in foo1
           group f by f.Name into g
           select new {Name = "Foo1 " + g.Key, Avg = g.Average(v=>v.Value)};

var res2 = from f in foo2
           group f by f.Name into g
           select new {Name = "Foo2 " + g.Key, Avg = g.Average(v=>v.Value)};


var result = res1.Union(res2).OrderBy(r=>r.Name);
```

EDIT:

because both `foo1` and `foo2` are in the same table, you could do this

```
var res1 = from t in table
           group t by t.Foo1 into g
           select new {Name = "Foo1 " + g.Key, Avg = g.Average(v=>v.Value)};

var res2 = from t in table
           group t by t.Foo2 into g
           select new {Name = "Foo2 " + g.Key, Avg = g.Average(v+>v.Value)};

var result = res1.Union(res2).OrderBy(r=>r.Name);
```

Comment: Right.  The technique is loosely referred to as "Group By Aggregate."

Comment: It's [Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, Robert! I will fix it.

Comment: I'm confused what this is doing. how does "from f in foo1" work? Doesn't this need to reference myDataTable somewhere?

Comment: from f in foo1 would apply this linq query to every object f in the collection foo1. I don't know your exact variable names, so you will probably have to adapt this a little bit. But this is a correct way to accomplish what you are trying to do quickly.

Comment: In your case I believe you would do something like `from f in dataTable.Select(f1=>new{Name = f1.Foo1, Value = f1.Value})` instead

Comment: Sorry, i'm still a LINQ newb and i'm a bit confused. Should I be using the line pquest said within a foreach on foobar? It complains that I need another select or group by clause.

Comment: no, this is your whole code. result at the end of this should have every row of your answer.

Comment: where does "from f in dataTable.Select(f1=>new{Name = f1.Foo1, Value = f1.Value})" actually fit into the original comment?

Comment: here I edited my post to make that line cleaner and show you what to do since all the data is in one table. That select line will not be in there because the way I just added is much cleaner

Comment: Ahh, so I guess I left this out in the OP. I'm not sure how many columns there will be, or how many entries will be in foobar. Could I take the new code you wrote, and do it in a "foreach" over foobar, sticking each result in some list, and then unioning them all at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Well personally I never let anyone ever iterate through rows! That is the worst way to access data in a database.

The sql Query would be:

```
select 'Foo1' as FooName, foo1, avg(value)
from mytable 
group by Foo1
UNion all
select 'Foo2' as FooName, foo2, avg(value)
from mytable 
group by 2
```

Not sure how to translate that to linq. You don't say what db backend you have but this one is for SQL server. I imagine most other dbs have a similar avg function but it may not be exactly the same. 
Then use the user interface to manipulate how the data appears.

Comment: What if you don't know how many columns you're going to have?

Comment: Don;t you knw the database struture?

Comment: No, i don't know the structure at compile time.